# JEE pac4j. Exception in TokenValidator. BadJWTException: Signed ID token expected

Tags: pac4j

by validate of token in the TokenValidator (JEE pac4j) I get this exception.
com.nimbusds.jwt.proc.BadJWTException: Signed ID token expected

Could you please help me to understand it.
How I can get the signed token from service provider?
The idToken:
header - PlainHeader
algorithm - none

Service provider - Azure
pac4j-core version 4.4.0
jee-pac4j version 5.0.0

thank you in advance
Felix

Answer (score 0):

The ID token is provided by your OIDC server, you should configure it to return a signed ID token.